# Ajax ComboBox Change event in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using an Ajax Control Tool Kit Combobox in my project. I want to trigger a change event when I change the value of the Combobox. I goolgled it a lot but there are no proper solution.

The ajax combobox is comprised of a textbox, a button and a list. I figured out the textbox id and I am trying to provide a change event to it. The change event is not working. But it will trigger the blur,select events.

this is the bit of code that I am using for the change event. I am not able to figure out why the change event is not working.

```
$('#' + $('.DDlCmbEmpID')[0].id + '_TextBox').bind("change",function (event) {
        alert("Sample");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to catch selected index changing on client:

```
$find("<%= XXXXXX.ClientID %>").set_selectedIndex = function (newIndex) {
     Sys.Extended.UI.ComboBox.prototype.set_selectedIndex.apply(this, [newIndex]);
     alert(newIndex);
 };
```

Substitute `XXXXXX` ion script above with server id (or BehaviorID if presented) of ComboBox extender.
Put this script at very bottom of page (not putting into `$(document).ready` )

Sript below tested on this page: [ComboBox Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx)

```
 $find("ctl00_SampleContent_ComboBox1").set_selectedIndex = function (newIndex) {
     Sys.Extended.UI.ComboBox.prototype.set_selectedIndex.apply(this, [newIndex]);
     alert(newIndex);
 };
```

Comment: I am getting an error when is use this ** Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'set_selectedIndex': object is null or undefined**